# How does react decide to replace vs update a component?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, animation, svg

The following code

```
function Baz({on}) {
  const rect1 = <rect x='10' y='10' fill='red' width='10' height='10' />
  const rect2 = <rect x='80' y='10' fill='red' width='10' height='10' />
  const Rect3 = () => <rect x='10' y='80' fill='red' width='10' height='10' />
  const Rect4 = () => <rect x='80' y='80' fill='red' width='10' height='10' />
  return (
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      { on ? rect1 : rect2 }
      { on ? <Rect3 /> : <Rect4 /> }
    </svg>
  );
}
```

will animate the transition from rect1 to rect2 (when css transitions are turned on) but not the transition from Rect3 to Rect4.

Why is this and is there any way to work around it?

A jsfiddle which shows what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/2jLtn39z/

Comment: This is not possible with CSS transactions as when we switch components it completely re-renders the HTML, you  can try with addon `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` may be that can help you

Comment: @SurajWasnik Thanks! Interesting concept. I found a solution which works in my case, manually calling render and passing the rendered element instead of the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some helpful answers I found a solution. Changing the <Rect3 /> (which is mounting Rect3 as a Component) to { Rect3() } (which returns the jsx elements and inserts them into the parent component, not creating any new components) makes the animation work. This also works with svgs imported as ReactComponents but since the imported svg is a class-component not a functional component you need to call it's render method instead.

An updated fiddle with the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/Ld6e0zyj/

```
const useState = React.useState
function Svg() {
  const [on, setOn] = useState(true);
  const toggle = () => setOn(on => !on);
  const rect1 = <rect x='10' y='10' fill='red' width='10' height='10' />;
  const rect2 = <rect x='80' y='10' fill='red' width='10' height='10' />;
  const Rect3 = () => <rect x='10' y='80' fill='red' width='10' height='10' />;
  class Rect4 extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <rect x='80' y='80' fill='red' width='10' height='10' />;
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        { on ? rect1 : rect2 }
        { on ? Rect3() : new Rect4().render() }
      </svg>
      <button onClick={toggle}> Toggle </button>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<Svg />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the first one update because you are changing the jsx elements, as opposed to the second one where you are replacing the component with another one.

Comment: Yes! Can I turn the components into elements to work around that somehow? I tried using React.createElement but it has no effect. With these simple functional components it is possible to just call the function (i.e. change <Rect3 /> to Rect() in the code) but that doesn't work for most values of the type 'ReactComponent'.